# Can I access packages within embedded ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, erb, configuration-files

I made an XML configuration file that contains information to be accessed from both my Ruby script files and my HTML files. For Ruby purposes, this file contains things like links and admin authentication credentials that the script will need to pull from my database (I know this isn't safe--that's not an issue for me right now). For the HTML, it contains titles and other graphical information for the widgets where I'll be displaying this received information.

I was able to access the XML file in Ruby with the following:

```
require 'xmlconfigfile'

parent_directory = File.expand_path(".")
config = XmlConfigFile.new(parent_directory + '/configuration_file.xml')

info_i_need = config["/config/path_to_info/the_info"]
```

No problems there. Now, in the HTML, each widget is assigned a name, and I'd like to replace those names with strings that are located in this XML file. So I tried using embedded Ruby:

```
<div data-title=<% XmlConfigFile.new(File.expand_path(".") + '/configuration_file.xml')["/config/path_to_info/the_info"] %> ></div>
```

I didn't really expect this to work. I'm not sure if you can/should access Ruby packages in this way, but I can't find any other way to get the information I need into the HTML.

I really appreciate any corrections to this code or suggestions to alternate approaches. Thanks!

Comment: `<% ... %>` does not render use `<%= ... %>` the `=` is interpreted as closely as possible to display the return value where as without the `=` the return value is ignored from the display context. While I agree this is probably not the best way to go about this hopefully you can get your intended result out of it.

Comment: @engineersmnky Wow, that did it! Working as expected now. Thanks! I'll have to do some research to find a better alternative when I have the time.